# Ads Not loading in MoPub IOS-SWIFT - Banner

Tags: ios, swift, ads, mopub

I am currently working on integrating ads in my app. For Advertisement i am using `MoPub` Library.

I have done following steps for integration ads in mobile-ios-swift

1. I have also create the app on https://app.mopub.com/ account
2. Register Application
3. Create Ad-Units
4. Create Orders in order section
5. Add Creative Ads

App Side

1. Add **Pod** File
2. Add AdMob using **cocoa-pods**
3. Intialize sdk with **appID**
4. Create banner and load **using unit-ad-id**

Following is my code

```
      DispatchQueue.main.async {

        let appID_adMOb = "80cda55523494caa97b759a732xxxxxx";


        let sdkConfig = 
         MPMoPubConfiguration.init(adUnitIdForAppInitialization: 
                                   appID_adMOb)

        sdkConfig.globalMediationSettings = [];
        sdkConfig.mediatedNetworks = [];
        sdkConfig.advancedBidders = nil;

        MoPub.sharedInstance().initializeSdk(with: sdkConfig) {
            self.bannerAdView = MPAdView.init(adUnitId: 
            "dbf9f8dcdfb44b1c817f2429b1xxxxxx", size: self.adSize)

            self.bannerAdView?.delegate = self

            let bounds : CGRect = self.view.bounds
            var adFrame = CGRect()

            adFrame.size = 
            self.bannerAdView!.sizeThatFits(bounds.size)
            adFrame.origin.x = (bounds.size.width- 
            adFrame.size.width)/2
            adFrame.origin.y = bounds.size.height - 
            adFrame.size.height

            self.bannerAdView?.autoresizingMask = .flexibleWidth
            self.bannerAdView!.frame = adFrame

            self.view?.addSubview(self.bannerAdView!)

            self.bannerAdView?.loadAd()
        }


}
```

Here the app_id which is display in url when i click on app which is like *https://app.mopub.com/app?key=80cda55523494caa97b759xxxxxx*

[image]

and load using ad unit id which also appear when click on any ad-unit in URL.

The Problem is out of 100 one of my advertise loading 2-3 times and when i change different ad-unit-id all time i get following error

> *MOPUB: Banner view (dbf9f8dcdfb44b1c817f2429b1c23d36) failed. Error: Error Domain=MoPubSDKNetworkDomain Code=21 "no data found in the NSHTTPURLResponse" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=no data found in the NSHTTPURLResponse}

What i am doing wrong here?

Can anyone please correct me.

Help will really appriciated :)

Comment: I have resolved the issue. If any one need help please let me know. I will help you for sure :)

Comment: What did you do?

Comment: Hi @Cyupa
Where did you stuck? Please share me the code snippet so that i can guide you

Comment: I think my payments account has not been yet accepted at this point and that’s why it ain’t working. I will follow up in a couple of days, thanks.

Comment: Did you able to work with sandbox ?

Comment: @Cyupa , to see ads will not requires the payment , you can see it with integration without payment.

Comment: Looked at the docs on https://developers.mopub.com/docs/ios/ but I can't seem to find a sandbox mode.

Comment: Yeahh i know , sandbox means to development mode , they have not define sandbox , sorry my mistake. And yes for display ads you don't need to pay for banner and industrial ads

Comment: @Anita, how did you solve this? I've been having this issue since upgrading to Mopub 5.0, and the banner ad comes up with a blank white screen

Comment: @AppsBeyond , Did you set image when you create orders ?

Comment: I am facing issue because i am setting wrong ids for load banner and ads , give me more detail for what you have done so that i can assist you in better way

Answer (score 0):

You might wanna check out this:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/native-ads-no-ads-found-for-ad-unit/35763

Where it is mentioned that:

> You might need to give the server some time to traffic an ad to that
>   ad unit ID.

So if you just created a MoPub account, then directly implemented the SDK, you might not get the ad shown directly, at least on your simulator and on your development environment.